# Excel: how can I use a cell value as part of a range?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm working with a large Excel file on a monthly basis.  In this file I have to find something like a `sum` as in

```
=sum(S2:AC2)
```

The problem is that the column of the last cell in the range changes.  I would like to be able to do something like this:

In a say cell `S1` I enter a value `AC`  and then later I can write

```
=sum(S2:value(S1)2)
```

and have this have the same effect as though I had written

```
=sum(S2:AC2)
```

I know this can be done.  I've seen it a very long time ago.  It would be a huge time saver.  I have hundreds of lines of the for `=sum(S2:AC2)`.  But next month they may all have to change to `=sum(S2:BF2)`.  To have one place to change the end of the range would be nice.

Incidentally, the row number actually changes too, but in an entirely predictable manner.

Ideally I would like to be able to concatenate the name such as:

```
=sum(S2: & S1 & row() )
```

where I'm using `row()` to get the current row number

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be achieved with a very elegant formula:

```
=SUM($S$2:INDIRECT($S$1&ROW()))
```

Comment: it's a nice trick, esp. when trying to avoid volatility in dynamically named ranges! Instead of the volatile `=OFFSET($A$1,0,0,rows,cols)`, `=$A$1:INDEX($A:$Z,rows,cols)` will produce the same result, but is non-volatile! :-)

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use INDIRECT like this

`=SUM(INDIRECT("S2:"&S1&"2"))`

....but that means "hardcoding" the row number....

If you don't have gaps in the data it might be better to define a "dynamic named range" based on the number of values in the row, e.g. define a name Range based on this formula

`=OFFSET($S$2,0,0,1,COUNTA($S$2:$IV$2))`

then you can just use

`=SUM(Range)`

Comment: I can't have it hardcode the row number.  That needs to change.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just sum a larger range, e.g. `=SUM(S2:IV2)`? - any blanks in there will just be ignored. Will there be the same number of values in each row?

Comment: Yes.  There is other stuff happening in the later columns.  It's a bad project design, but I'm stuck with it.

Answer (score 1):

I've managed something of a work around.  But, I'm not happy with it.

Let's say that in cells:

```
 cell(AB1) = "AD"
 cell(AC1) = "AG"
```

then in row `x` I have the following

```
 cell(ABx)=AB$1 & row()
 cell(ACx)=AC$1 & row()
```

and then I can set

```
 cell(AAx)=sum(indirect(ABx &":"& ACx))
```

While this works, it means I've got to manually create two columns with the desired code.

It would be nice to be able to do something like

```
 cell(AAx)=sum(indirect(AB$1 & row() &":"& AC$1 & row()))
```

Oh, and it does work!!!

Comment: Yes, that last formula should work - is that what you're saying?